# Go - high performance communication between goroutines?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am trying to write a small game server in Go. I basically copied example from WebSocket library (https://github.com/gorilla/websocket).

Every second, servers executes function `s.tick()` which sends current time to the user. This works fine when users do not perform any actions.

When a user joins, leaves or sends a message, information is send over one of three channels (one for each action) and corresponding action is executed, however `s.tick()` is either skipping or delayed. I have noticed, that if users perform actions all the time, `s.tick()` will never be called.

Here's the output:

```
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:11 CET
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:12 CET
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:13 CET
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:15 CET
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:16 CET
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:17 CET

-- users joining and leaving

Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:25 CET
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:26 CET
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:27 CET
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:28 CET
Mon, 05 Dec 2016 20:19:29 CET
```

I tried to check what is causing so much delay between the actions (none of these actions is taking long time) and my only thought is that:

- my code is just bad (very likely)
- Go's channels are slow

I checked time at the beginning of a loop and at the beginning of a case clause and it is often taking more than 200ms to even receive data from channel. Having said that, how can I improve the performance of this solution? I can't seem to be able to have server working well at one tick per second, let alone 60.

Below's snippet of my code:

```
type GameServer struct {
    players map[*Player]bool

    register   chan *Player
    unregister chan *Player

    broadcast chan []byte
}

func (s *GameServer) broadcastMessage(msg []byte) {
    for player := range s.players {
        player.messages <- msg
    }
}

func (s *GameServer) tick() {
    s.broadcastMessage([]byte(time.Now().Format(time.RFC1123)))
}

// question is mostly related to this function
func (s *GameServer) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case _ = <-time.NewTicker(time.Second).C:
            s.tick()
        case client := <-s.register:
            s.players[client] = true
        case client := <-s.unregister:
            delete(s.players, client)
        case msg := <-s.broadcast:
            s.broadcastMessage(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you need to add a global time Ticker on to your GameServer struct that gets initialized only once, and change your first select case to `s.ticker.C`. At the moment you are creating a new ticker every time the run function gets called therefore that will only execute tick in the instance where no other channels have any data in them for at least a second from when run is called, which explains the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: You're creating a new Ticker on every iteration, so your'e leaking resources on top of not having a stable tick interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
type GameServer struct {
    players map[*Player]bool

    register   chan *Player
    unregister chan *Player

    broadcast chan []byte

    ticker *time.Ticker //use a single "global" *time.Ticker

}

func (s *GameServer) broadcastMessage(msg []byte) {
    for player := range s.players {
        player.messages <- msg
    }
}

func (s *GameServer) tick() {
    s.broadcastMessage([]byte(time.Now().Format(time.RFC1123)))
}

// question is mostly related to this function
func (s *GameServer) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case _ = <- s.Ticker.C: //use the "global" *time.Ticker instead of creating a new one every time
            s.tick()
        case client := <-s.register:
            s.players[client] = true
        case client := <-s.unregister:
            delete(s.players, client)
        case msg := <-s.broadcast:
            s.broadcastMessage(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think you want to be creating a new time.Ticker every call to `run`. The above should fix your problems.

Comment: But I only call `run` once and then it loops until process is killed.

Comment: still each time the for loop goes over you are creating a new ticker, you could just move the ticker creation outside the for loop, either way, it is creating the ticker every iteration which is the cause of your bug.

Comment: Got it, that indeed works. I misunderstood your comment on top. Thank you :)